# Why don't I get a NullPointerException in Groovy in this case?

Tags: groovy, null

I have this test code:

```
def test = null

test.each {  }
```

Why don't I get any exception?

Comment: Related questiuon here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480195/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-nullobject-class-in-groovy

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for the link to the related question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The implementation of `each` tries to call the `iterator` method of it's target **in a null-safe fashion**. If `each` is called on a null object, or an object without an `iterator` method, nothing happens.

I haven't seen the source code, but it could look something like this§

```
Object each(Closure closure) {

  if (this?.respondsTo("iterator")) {

    def iterator = this.iterator()

    while (iterator.hasNext() {
      def item = iterator.next()
      closure(item)
    }
  }
  return this
}
```

§ In reality, this method is probably written in Java rather than Groovy

Comment: Actually, it's in `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.java`, where there is a method defined as `public Iterator iterator() { return Collections.EMPTY_LIST.iterator(); }` So the `NullObject` (`null`) returns an `Iterator` to an empty `List` when queried by `each`

Comment: Hehe, enjoying your fantasy world too much eh? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A null value when using the each closure is the same as a  collection with 0 elements. If you have the code

```
def test=null
test.each {println "In closure with value "+it}
```

The print statement won't execute. If you change test to

```
def test=[1,2,3]
```

you will get output.