# @CompileStatic gives NullPointerException

Tags: groovy

Why just annotating with @CompileStatic makes the below code to give NullPointerException?

```
class GroovyEach {
    static def main(args) {
        List items = null

        items.each {
            println 'hello'
        }

    }
}
```

Below code gives exception.

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class GroovyEach {
    static def main(args) {
        List items = null

        items.each {
            println 'hello'
        }

    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1372)
    at trial.GroovyEach.main(GroovyEach.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: could you provide a stacktrace also?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, you reproduce the stacktrace easily yourself.

Comment: @Opal I believe so. But it requires 20 minutes to setup new project, configure environment, copy code, and try it, right? isn't it easier to just copy existing stracktrace to the question?

Comment: No, just copy the latter example into groovy console and you're done.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, I'm sorry but probably it's not enough, can;t reproduce it :/

Comment: Igor and Opal - I have added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the inverse of an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472795/why-dont-i-get-a-nullpointerexception-in-groovy-in-this-case).  When compiled statically, `items` is of type `List`, when not compiled statically the type is `NullObject`, which retrieves the iterator in a null-safe fashion.  This is trivial to demonstrate.

This works

```
class GroovyEach {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        List items = null
        (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject) items
    }
}
```

this fails with `[Static type checking] - Inconvertible types: cannot cast java.util.List to org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject`

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class GroovyEach {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        List items = null
        (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject) items
    }
}
```